# Disable optimizely for google amp

Tags: javascript, php, optimizely

Is there a way to turn this javascript code into PHP?

```js
window['optimizely'] = window['optizmizely'] || [];
window['optimizely'].push(["disable"]);
```

Comment: That's a client-side tracking library.  You need to understand the difference between the client and the server.

Comment: To my knowledge, AMP can't have JavaScript, so Optimizely isn't going to run anyways.

Comment: Oh, it runs with Javascript, but it throws an error

Comment: @sLaks - thank you! I'm too new to programming

Answer (score 1):

Optimizely installs on your site via a javascript file. AMP as a spec doesn't use javascript at all -- source: https://www.ampproject.org/how-it-works/

Per the question, you don't disable optimizely by converting that javascript to PHP; you instead just don't load the `<script src="//cdn.optimizely.com/js/12345678.js"></script>` file on your AMP pages.

Comment: Hi TomFuertes - I have a wordpress site, so I want to use optimizely on regular (non-amp) pages. The <script src="//cdn.optimizely.com/js/12345678.js"></script> gets injected into all pages. I don't know how to exclude it from amp pages.

Comment: File a ticket with your AMP page plugin. They should remove all <script> tags by default like this one does https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/